# Rails 4 Unique Grandchildren count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up an event management app in Rails 4 that includes four models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :registrations
  has_many :contacts, through: :registrations
end

class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :contact

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registrations
  has_many :activities, through: :registrations
end
```

I'm trying to get a count of unique contacts registered for any activity at an event.

I tried creating a method in the Event model:

```
def unique_contacts_count
  activities.contacts.distinct.count
end
```

But I'm getting a NoMethod error for "contacts" when I call it.

Very new to coding and rails, so I'd welcome any approach.

Comment: You can try activities.contacts.group(:id).count

Comment: where is `activities` defined?

Comment: I believe activities is defined through the has_many association? self.activities might be the implied method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activities.contacts` doesn't work because what is returned by calling `activites` is an `ActiveRecordRelation`

I am not 100% sure this would work or would be the best answer but you might can try adding something like this to Event:

```
has_many :contacts, through: :activities
```

Also, you might be able to use something like:

`activities.joins(:contacts)` to some success

Answer (score 0):

Is activities an active record model?

If not you will need to do something like this

```
Activity.find(:id).contacts.distinct.count
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach is

```
activities.collect(&:contacts).distinct.count
```